# ID элемента недопустим

Tags: android

Здравствуйте, пытаюсь создать GUI для приложения декларативно в IntelliJ idea, при этом когда создаю relative layout выстраиваю расположение вью через ID, при этом идея в превьюшке всё делает как задано в параметрах, а вот на этапе компиляции выводится ошибка, что ID недопустим. Сам ID просто int (хотя идея хватает и со строкой).

Comment: XML ресурса на который ругается можно посмотреть?

Comment: KoVadim созидайте пожалуйста ответ, чтобы можно было закрыть вопрос. 

Всегда раньше делал GUI в коде(

Comment: код в студию! Экстрасенс болеет!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

думаю, автор вопроса туда вместо `@+id/tttt` вбил `112312312`.